# Twilio Outgoing Message Error with Free Trial

Tags: twilio

I am trying to use Twilio free trial to accept a message from one number and send it to another. The issue is that I cannot send a message from my bot to another number, only my own. Is this inaccessible by the free trial or am I doing something wrong? I am using the flow chart method to create my application.

Comment: Can you verify the other number, so you can send them an SMS when in trial mode? https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180048-Adding-a-Verified-Phone-Number-or-Caller-ID-with-Twilio

Answer (score 0):

When [in trial mode you can only send messages to numbers that you have verified](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360036052753-Twilio-Free-Trial-Limitations#h_306ae9a5-c8bd-4859-9459-98acb7b4e3e3).

You have two options:

- [Verify the number](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180048-Adding-a-Verified-Phone-Number-or-Caller-ID-with-Twilio) you are trying to send to
- [Upgrade your account](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183208-Upgrading-to-a-paid-Twilio-Account)